# Show or hide tablix based on parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

The scenario is that there should be a dropdown parameter to select table name and when the user clicks on View report, he should see the data from that particular table.

Both the tables have different columns.

I tried creating different datasets for both tables and created two tablix and bound them to their respective datasets and put a condition for show/hide tablix based on expression.

But still I get error that the column(from other table) does not exist when a select a table.

I am new to SSRS, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter to your report (TablixChosePara). With your different options:

```
=1  'Tablix1
=2  'Tablix2
```

Then add two tablixes to your report with two different columns or datasets. Then go to tablix properties and write the following expresson under 'Show or hide tablix based on expression'

```
=IIF(Parameters!TablixChosePara.Value = 1, True, False)
```

And fot the second tablix l:

```
=IIF(Parameters!TablixChosePara.Value = 2, True, False)
```

Comment: I have created a dropdown parameter which has table names-Table1 and table2. And I have created expression like: =IIF(Parameters!TableName.Value = "Table1", True, False) for tablix 1 and =IIF(Parameters!TableName.Value = "Table2", True, False) for tablix2. But it still throws error. When I select table1 from dropdown, it throws error that col1(which is of table2) is not present and vice versa.

Comment: So to be clear, you have two datasets, two tablix objects and a single parameter, correct? If so then the answer provided should work (except the true and false are the wrong way round as you are setting the `hidden` property, so True = hidden).If this is not the case then please update your question to show the the report design, both datasets format (the output columns) and any other relevant code/settings/parameters etc.

Comment: It depends on your value. You have a label for the parameter and a value. The label is that what the user sees and the value is the actual value in the background. So if your label is `Table1` and the value is `1` then the expression goes like `=IIF(Parameters!YourParameterName.Value = 1, False, True)`. And yes Alan was right, you have to switch the `true` and `False`.